# Cannot remove "."/".." from scandir array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, scandir

I was using scandir to get some filenames into an array and then trying to use an if stmt to slice the "." and ".." from the array if they existed, but that did not work so I tried to only echo the image if the variable was not ".." or "." and that did not work. Example Code Below:

```
if ($pages[$pageIndex] == "." || $pages[$pageIndex] == "..") {
  array_slice($pages, 0, 2);
  print_r($pages);
}
# And

while ($i < $pagesLength) {
  if ($pages[$pageIndex] != "." || $pages[$pageIndex] != "..") {
    echo "<img src='series/series_" . rawurlencode($_GET['series']) . "/series_" . rawurlencode($newLink) . "/" . rawurlencode($pages[$pageIndex]) . "'>";
    $pageIndex = $pageIndex + 1;
    $i++;
  }
}                            }
```

They Stayed no matter what I did, How can I get rid of them?

Array Content:
[image: array contents]

Comment: what does the structure look like?

Comment: If you mean the structure of the array I will update the post to include an image of how it is printed.

Comment: Is that the content of `$pages` or `$pages[$pageIndex]`? What is `$pageIndex`?

Comment: you could do a for loop starting at 2 (`for ($i = 2; $i <= $pagesLength; $i++) {`)

Comment: Oh yeah your right, I guess a while loop isnt exactly necessary here. and $pages[$pageindex] is just one item from the array. the pageindex variable is a integer that increases each loop. Thanks for the Idea Ill go try it now.

Comment: @Thatguy553 Best of luck

Comment: Worked Like a charm, Thanks! That even shortens my code by a line or two now that im not using an entirely seperate variable to index.

Comment: Done, again, thanks for the help.

Comment: there is no scandir in your code

Comment: Yeah, it was used previously in the code and it successfully threw all of the filenames inside the directory I wanted into an array, I just needed to know how to remove the "."'s from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop starting at line 2 to skip the `.` / `..`.

```
for ($i = 2; $i <= $pagesLength; $i++) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to strip out any hidden files would be:

```
$pages = preg_grep('/^(?!\.{1,2}$)/', $pages);
```

one other quick way would be to use [`array_diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).

```
$pages = array_diff($pages, array('.', '..'));
```